# Custom listView in a fragment as a viewPager layout

Tags: android, eclipse

I am creating a list that must be inside a fragment.This fragment has a custom `UI` that `listView` is a child for it.
I can add rows to this `listView`, but I want to customize it. In addition i want to get data from my database.
Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `Tablelayout` with customized rows. I had a project and it is some codes inside it:

xml:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_rew" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/amval_gardaani_actions_pagenotxt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView2"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="اسکن شده"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RLayoutSort"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/LinearLayout1" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/sort"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:onClick="ChangeSortType"
        android:src="@android:drawable/arrow_up_float" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/sort" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:text="مرتب سازی:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Count"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView1"
        android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:text="0"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="22dp"
        android:text="تعداد :"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.33"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/exit"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="#ffffbb33"
            android:onClick="exit_scanned"
            android:text="بازگشت" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.33"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/delete"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="#ffff4444"
            android:onClick="delete_scanned"
            android:text="حذف" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.33"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/save"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="#ff99cc00"
            android:onClick="save_scanned"
            android:text="ثبت" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/TableLayout01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/RLayoutSort"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_margin="3dp"
    android:stretchColumns="1" >
</TableLayout>
```

Java Class:

```
package com.Sinap.Asset;


import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class Amval_gardaani_Actions_not_Scanned extends Fragment
    {

        Cursor      

cursor;
    TableLayout     table;
    TableRow        row;
    TextView        tv;
    ListView        lv;
    private String  TAG = "Amval_gardaani_Actions_not_Scanned";
    View            rootView;

    public static Amval_gardaani_Actions_Fragment newInstance(String title)
        {

            Amval_gardaani_Actions_Fragment pageFragment =
                                                            new Amval_gardaani_Actions_Fragment();



            return pageFragment;
        }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {

            rootView =
                        inflater.inflate(
                                R.layout.amval_gardaani_actions_not_scanned,
                                container,
                                false);
            Initialize();
            return rootView;
        }

    private void Initialize()
        {

            lv =
                    (ListView) rootView
                            .findViewById(R.id.Asset_Scanned_listView);

            Display_Rows();
        }

    private void Display_Rows()
        {


            Log.d(TAG, "Displaying Rows...");


            cursor = new Data_Assets(getActivity()).query("1=1", null);

            for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getCount(); i++)
                {
                    Log.d(TAG, "turn: " + i);


                    cursor.moveToPosition(i);

                    table =
                            (TableLayout) rootView
                                    .findViewById(R.id.TableLayout01);
                    Log.d(TAG, "TableLayout added");

                    row = new TableRow(getActivity());
                    Log.d(TAG, "TableRow added");

                    tv = new TextView(getActivity());
                    Log.d(TAG, "TextView added");

                    tv.setText(cursor.getString(cursor
                            .getColumnIndexOrThrow("barcode")));
                    row.addView(tv);
                    tv.setPadding(5, 15, 5, 15);
                    Log.d(TAG, "Column 1 added");

                    tv = new TextView(getActivity());
                    tv.setText(cursor.getString(cursor
                            .getColumnIndexOrThrow("name")));
                    row.addView(tv);
                    tv.setPadding(5, 15, 5, 15);
                    Log.d(TAG, "Column 2 added");

                    tv = new TextView(getActivity());
                    tv.setText(cursor.getString(cursor
                            .getColumnIndexOrThrow("description")));
                    row.addView(tv);
                    tv.setPadding(5, 15, 5, 15);
                    Log.d(TAG, "Column 3 added");

                    row.setTag((i + 1) + "");
                    row.setOnClickListener(make_rowClick());

                    table.addView(row, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                }



            Log.d(TAG, "Rows Displayed");

        }

    private OnClickListener make_rowClick()
        {

            return new OnClickListener()
                {

                    public void onClick(View arg0)
                        {

                            Toast.makeText(
                                    getActivity(),
                                    "Row "
                                        + arg0.getTag()
                                        + ": "
                                        + ((TextView)((TableRow)arg0).getChildAt(0))
                                                .getText()
                                        + "/"
                                        + ((TextView) ((TableRow)arg0).getChildAt(1))
                                                .getText()
                                        + "/"
                                        + ((TextView) ((TableRow)arg0).getChildAt(2))
                                                .getText(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                };

        }
}
```

Please tell us the result. I am willing to solve your problem :)